# Plotting xarray.DataArray and Geopandas together - aspect ratio errors

Tags: matplotlib, python-xarray, rasterio

I am trying to create two images side by side: one satellite image alone, and next to it, the same satellite image with outlines of agricultural fields. My raster data "raster_clip" is loaded into rioxarray (original satellite image from NAIP, converted from .sid to .tif), and my vector data "ag_clip" is in geopandas. My code is as follows:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols = 2, figsize=(14,8))
raster_clip.plot.imshow(ax=ax1)
raster_clip.plot.imshow(ax=ax2)
ag_clip.boundary.plot(ax=ax1, color="yellow")
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the y axes in each plot to be the same. When the vector data is excluded, then the two plots end up the same shape and size.

[image: Misaligned raster/vector plots]

I have tried the following:

- Setting sharey=True in the subplots method. Doesn't affect shape of resulting images, just removes the tic labels on the second image.
- Setting "aspect='equal'" in the imshow method, leads to an error, which doesn't make sense because the 'aspect' kwarg is listed in the documentation for xarray.plot.imshow.

`plt.imshow's 'aspect' kwarg is not available in xarray`

- Removing the "figsize" variable, doesn't affect the ratio of the two plots.

Comment: I agree that the ValueError does not make sense considering the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

not entirely related to your question but i've used cartopy before for overlaying a GeoDataFrame to a DataArray

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
ax = plt.subplot(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ds.plot(ax=ax)
gdf.plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree the ValueError doesn't make sense given the documentation. Another notation also described in the documentation works, however:

```
# raster is a xarray DataArray

raster.plot.imshow(size = 5, aspect = 1) # ~ width(5) * height(5)

help(raster.plot.imshow)
    ...
    size : scalar, optional
        If provided, create a new figure for the plot with the given size:
        *height* (in inches) of each plot. See also: ``aspect``.
    aspect : "auto", "equal", scalar or None, optional
        Aspect ratio of plot, so that ``aspect * size`` gives the *width* in
        inches. Only used if a ``size`` is provided.
    ...
```